# How do I delete all records in IndexedDB

Tags: javascript, indexeddb

I have an IndexedDB where I store all cart orders. On checkout, the cart needs to be clear. I'm trying to loop through each order and delete, but somehow, only the first order gets deleted. Here is my code:

```
const clear_cart = () => {
    let objectCart = db.transaction('cart').objectStore('cart');

    objectCart.openCursor().onsuccess = function(e){
        let cursor = e.target.result;
        if(cursor){
           let cartId = cursor.value.id;

           let transaction = db.transaction(['cart'], 'readwrite');
           let objectToDelete = transaction.objectStore('cart');
           let request = objectCart.objectToDelete(cartId);

           transaction.oncomplete = () => {
                console.log(`cart ${cartId} is deleted!`);
           }

           cursor.continue();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I made some tweaks to the suggestion of dmigo and this solved my problem. Here is the code

```
const clear_cart = () => {
    let objectCart = db.transaction('cart').objectStore('cart');

    let transaction = db.transaction(['cart'], 'readwrite');
    let objectToDelete = transaction.objectStore('cart');

    objectToDelete.clear().onsuccess = function(e){
        console.log(`the cart is clear!`);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would try the [clear method](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/IDBObjectStore/clear) of the `objectStore`.

```js
const clear_cart = () => {
    let objectCart = db.transaction(['cart'], 'readwrite').objectStore('cart');

    objectCart.clear().onsuccess = function(e){
        console.log(`the cart is clear!`);
    }
}
```

Comment: I was getting an error of database is read only. I make some tweaks to your code, i.e. set the cart to read write and it worked. :-)